# Como combinar dos byte arrays con un delimitador entre ambos, en C#

Tags: c#

Mi pregunta es simplemente como podría juntar dos byte array y delimitarlos. En el siguiente ejemplo los uno y los escribo como un único fichero. Pero, Primero no sé como podría unirlos con un delimitador una coma o algo para separarlos y que cuando arranque mi programa sea capaz de obtenerlos por medio de un split. El código es el siguiente:

```
//Everything seems fine -> Reading bytes
Console.WriteLine("[*] Reading Data...");
byte[] plainBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

//Yep, got bytes -> Encoding
Console.WriteLine("[*] Encoding Data...");
byte[] encodedBytes = encodeBytes(plainBytes, pass);

Console.WriteLine("[*] Save to Output File... ");

//Leer el fichero
Console.WriteLine("[*] Reading fichero...");
byte[] Stub = File.ReadAllBytes("rutafichero");

// ::: Create new List of bytes
var list = new List<byte>();
list.AddRange(encodedBytes);
list.AddRange(Stub);

// ::: Call ToArray to convert List to array
byte[] resultado = list.ToArray();

//write bytes
File.WriteAllBytes(outFile, resultado);

//File.WriteAllBytes(outFile, encodedBytes);
Console.WriteLine("Done!");

Console.WriteLine("\n[*] File successfully encoded!");
```

Entonces mi primer byte array (fichero 1) se juntara + con el otro byte array(fichero 2) y se escribirá en un solo fichero. Cuando arranque el fichero resultante seré capaz de obtener los dos array por medio de un split. Ese es el objetivo que quería llevar a cabo y que por desgracia no supe como porque primero que no se `delimitar dos byte array combinados` y segundo como extraerlos después. El objetivo era hacerlo con un assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personalmente, si deseas escribr 2 arrays en un archivo y poder leerlos por separado más tarde, yo usaría la clase [`BinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx), para que te lo haga todo automático. La idea de usar un split con una coma no me suena bien en este caso.

Por ejemplo, según tu ejemplo, partiendo de los 2 byte arrays siguientes:

```
byte[] encodedBytes = ...;
byte[] Stub = ...;
```

Puedes escribir los 2 arrays a un archivo de la siguiente manera:

```
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(outFile, FileMode.Create)))
{
    writer.Write(encodedBytes.Length);
    writer.Write(encodedBytes);
    writer.Write(Stub.Length);
    writer.Write(Stub);
}
```

Y luego los puedes recuperar usando la clase [`BinaryReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) de la forma siguiente:

```
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(outFile, FileMode.Open)))
{
    encodedBytes = reader.ReadBytes(reader.ReadInt32());
    Stub = reader.ReadBytes(reader.ReadInt32());
}
```