# Como cargar un assembly usando un delimitador en c#

Tags: c#

Hola si escribo esta pregunta es porque he intentado de todo pero no ha funcionado. La unica manera posible es dropeando o poniendo el fichero en disco pero me parecia un programa ineficiente así que me decidi por añadir el assembly al ejecutable y luego arrancarlo desde un solo fichero. Planteo aqui la pregunta por que sé que hay muy buenos programadores y tal vez alguien pueda explicarme un poco más cual es mi error. No hago apología a nada simplemente vi un programa que vi en la red y no ha sido posible optimizarlo por un simple delimitador.
El código del programa que junta es:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Crypt
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //No Arguments -> Exit
            if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Syntax: crypter.exe <Exe/Dll to get Encrypted> <Password> (Optional: output file name)");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            String file = args[0];
            String pass = args[1];
            String outFile = "Crypted.exe";

            //If Output Name is specified -> Set it
            if (args.Length == 3)
            {
                outFile = args[2];
            }

            //File doesn't exist -> Exit
            if (!File.Exists(file))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[!] The selected File doesn't exist!");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            //Everything seems fine -> Reading bytes
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Reading Data...");
            byte[] plainBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

            //Yep, got bytes -> Encoding
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Encoding Data...");
            byte[] encodedBytes = encodeBytes(plainBytes, pass);

            Console.WriteLine("[*] Save to Output File... ");

            //Leer el stub
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Reading Stub...");
            byte[] Stub = File.ReadAllBytes("Stub.exe");

            //byte separador
            string strseperate = "BLAUMOLAMUCHO";
            byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strseperate);
            //byte[] toBytes = new byte[30];

            //write bytes
            //var stream
            //Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("skip.skip.exe");
            //Console.WriteLine(stream);
            var s = new MemoryStream();
            s.Write(Stub, 0, Stub.Length);
            s.Write(toBytes, 0, toBytes.Length);
            s.Write(encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.Length);
            var b3 = s.ToArray();
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(b3);


            //Stream stream = new MemoryStream(encodedBytes);
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"out.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
                fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");

            Console.WriteLine("\n[*] File successfully encoded!");
        }
        private static byte[] encodeBytes(byte[] bytes, String pass)
        {
            byte[] XorBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] ^= XorBytes[i % XorBytes.Length];
            }

            return bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

El código del programa que se encarga de arrancar el assembly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Resources;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace skip
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// MAIN
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Application.Run(new Form1());

            //leemos el byte array
            byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            //ruta appdata
            string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

            //obtenemos la string
            string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(file);

            //char[] delimiterChars = { 'D', 'E', 'L', 'I', 'M' , 'I', 'T', 'A', 'D', 'O', 'R'};
            char[] delimiterChars = { 'B', 'L', 'A', 'U', 'M' , 'O', 'L', 'A', 'M', 'U', 'C', 'H', 'O'};
            Console.WriteLine(delimiterChars);
            string[] arr=str.Split(new string[] { "BLAUMOLAMUCHO" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string a = arr[0];
            string b = arr[1];
            /*Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(b);
            Console.ReadKey();*/

            byte[] encodedBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b);
            //Console.WriteLine(encodedBytes);
            //var stream
            //Stream stream = new MemoryStream(encodedBytes);
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(encodedBytes);
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"tola.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
                fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());


         }

        private static void RunInternal(string exeName, String pass)
        {

            //Verify the Payload exists
            if (!File.Exists(exeName))
                return;

            //Read the raw bytes of the file
            byte[] resourcesBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(exeName);

            //Decrypt bytes from payload
            byte[] decryptedBuffer = null;
            decryptedBuffer = decryptBytes(resourcesBuffer, pass);



            //If .NET executable -> Run
            if (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedBuffer).Contains("</assembly>")) //Esto devuelve false
            {
                //Load the bytes as an assembly
                Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(decryptedBuffer);

                //Execute the assembly
                object[] parameters = new object[1];                //Don't know why but fixes TargetParameterCountException

                try{
                    exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, parameters);
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedBuffer));
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypt the Loaded Assembly Bytes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="payload"></param>
        /// <returns>Decrypted Bytes</returns>
        private static byte[] decryptBytes(byte[] bytes, String pass)
        {
            byte[] XorBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] ^= XorBytes[i % XorBytes.Length];
            }

            return bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

He intentado de muchas maneras pero la única que me ha funcionado es poniendolo como recurso. De esta manera, delimitando y separando por un delimitador no he conseguido hacerlo funcionar.

El error que me devuelve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Binario con delimitador:

```
MZ? ♥   ♦   ??  ?       @                                   ?   ♫▼?♫ ?  ?!?☺L?!T
his program cannot be run in DOS mode.
$       PE  L☺♥ ?4‼Y        ? ☻☺♂☺♂  ♫       N,       @    @      ☻  ♦       ♦
      ?   ☻      ♥ @?  ►  ►    ►  ►      ►           ?+  S    @   ♣
      `  ♀   ?*  ∟                                                         H
       .text   T♀       ♫   ☻                 `.rsrc    ♣   @   ♠   ►
   @  @.reloc  ♀    `   ☻   ▬              @  B                0,      H   ☻ ♣ ?
!  $      ☺   ☺  ♠                                                ‼0☻ @   ☺  ◄ (
↕
 ▬(‼
 (¶
o§
(▬

▼→(↨
♂(↑
♠o↓
(→
 (←
&*←0♥ ?   ☻  ◄ ☻(∟
‼♣◄♣-♣8?   ☻(▬

¶♂♠♥(♥  ♠♂(↑
o↓
r☺  po↔
▬?☺‼♣◄♣-9 (▲
o▼    ☺
¶       o
& ?¶‼♦ ◄♦(!
 (←
& ?   +↓ (↑
o↓
(→
 (←
& *☺►    P ↕b ¶▼  ☺‼0♣ B   ♥  ◄ ("
♥o#

        -?☻♀+*  BSJB☺ ☺     ♀   v4.0.30319    ♣ l   ?☻  #~  H♥  (♦  #Strings
p  ∟   #US ?  ►   #GUID   ?  ?☺  #Blob       ☻  ☺G§☻        ?%3 ▬  ☺       ☻   ♥
   ♦   #   ☼   ♥   ☺   ☻
 ☺     ♠ 0 ) ♠ ? h ♠ ? ? ♠ ? ? ♠ ? ? ♠ ♠☺? ♠ ▼☺? ♠ 8☺? ♠ S☺? ♠ n☺? ♠ ?☺?☺♠ ?☺?☺♠
 ?☺? ♠ ?☺? ♠ ◄☻?☺? %☻  ♠ T☻4☻♠ t☻4☻♠ ?☻)
 ?☻?☻♠ ?☻? ♠ 0♥&♥♠ B♥) _ N♥  ♠ v♥j♥♠ ?♥) ♠ ?♥) ♠ ?♥) ♠ ?♥? ♠ ?♥? ♠ ♦♦) ♠ #♦)
 ☺     ☺ ☺ ?☺► ‼ ← ♣ ☺ ☺ P     ? 7
 ☺ ?     ? < ♫ ☺ L!    ? H ¶ ♥   ☺ U   ☻ ]   ☺ b   ☻ ] ◄ ? ∟ ↓ ? ∟ ! ? ∟ ) ? ∟ 1
 ? ∟ 9 ? ∟ A ? ∟ I ? ∟ Q ? ∟ Y ? ! a ? ∟ i ? ∟ q ? ∟ y ? & ? ? , ? ? 1 ? ? 1 ? ?
☻
 ? ?☻: ? ♦♥? ? ↓♥D ? 5♥H ? \♥N ? ⌂♥T ? ?♥Y ? ?♥_ ? ?♥d ? ?♥p ? ?♥u ? ?♥z ? ?♥? ?
 ?♥? ? ?♥? ? ♫♦T ? →♦?   ? 5 . ; ☺. ‼ ? . ← ☺☺. # ☺☺. + ☺☺. 3 ? . ♂ ? . C ☺☺. S
☺☺. [ ▼☺. k I☺. s V☺. { _☺. ? h☺i ? ? ♦?  ☺             ←   ♦           ☺
♦           ☺ ?☻         <Module> skip.exe Program skip mscorlib System Object M
ain RunInternal decryptBytes exeName pass bytes System.Runtime.Versioning Target
FrameworkAttribute .ctor System.Reflection AssemblyTitleAttribute AssemblyDescri
ptionAttribute AssemblyConfigurationAttribute AssemblyCompanyAttribute AssemblyP
roductAttribute AssemblyCopyrightAttribute AssemblyTrademarkAttribute AssemblyCu
ltureAttribute System.Runtime.InteropServices ComVisibleAttribute GuidAttribute
AssemblyVersionAttribute AssemblyFileVersionAttribute System.Diagnostics Debugga
bleAttribute DebuggingModes System.Runtime.CompilerServices CompilationRelaxatio
nsAttribute RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute STAThreadAttribute System.Windows.Form
s Application EnableVisualStyles SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault Assembly GetE
xecutingAssembly get_Location System.IO File ReadAllBytes Environment SpecialFol
der GetFolderPath System.Text Encoding get_ASCII GetString Console WriteLine Con
soleKeyInfo ReadKey Exists String Contains Load MethodInfo get_EntryPoint Method
Base Invoke Exception get_Unicode GetBytes Byte  ↨< / a s s e m b l y >     ????
=??J?▲??R???z\V↓4??♥  ☺♣ ☻☺♫♫ ☻↔♣↔♣♫♦ ☺☺♫♦ ☺☺☻♣ ☺☺◄A♦ ☺♥  ☺♦☺   ♦ ☺☺☻♦  ↕U♥  ♫♣
♠↔♣↔♣↕U↔∟↕}☻♣ ☺↔♦↔♣☻G☺ →.NETFramework,Version=v4.0☺ T♫¶FrameworkDisplayName►.NET
 Framework 4    ☺ ♦Stub  ♣☺    ↨☺ ↕Copyright ??  2017  )☺ $0f86beb5-80bf-47f1-89
e1-df778adbda88  ♀☺ 1.0.0.0☺ ☺       ▲☺ ☺ T☻▬WrapNonExceptionThrows☺     ?4‼Y
 ☻   ∟☺  ?*  ?♀  RSDS§2??♦YL?{Q‼????☺   c:\Users\Androide\Desktop\CRYPTER SIN DR
OPEAR\Stub\obj\Debug\skip.pdb

                                                             ,          >,
                    0,                _CorExeMain mscoree.dll     ?%  @





                                  ☻ ►      ?↑   8  ?              ☺ ☺   P  ?
          ☺ ☺   h  ?              ☺     ?                 ☺     ?   ?@  ?☻
    0C  ?☺          ?☻4   V S _ V E R S I O N _ I N F O     ?♦??  ☺   ☺       ☺
    ?       ♦   ☺               D   ☺ V a r F i l e I n f o     $ ♦   T r a n s
l a t i o n       ?♦?☺  ☺ S t r i n g F i l e I n f o   ?☺  ☺ 0 0 0 0 0 4 b 0
4 ♣ ☺ F i l e D e s c r i p t i o n     S t u b      ☺ F i l e V e r s i o n
 1 . 0 . 0 . 0   4       ☺ I n t e r n a l N a m e   s k i p . e x e     H ↕ ☺ L
 e g a l C o p y r i g h t   C o p y r i g h t   ?     2 0 1 7   <       ☺ O r i
 g i n a l F i l e n a m e   s k i p . e x e     , ♣ ☺ P r o d u c t N a m e
 S t u b      ☺ P r o d u c t V e r s i o n   1 . 0 . 0 . 0   8 ☺ A s s e m b l
y   V e r s i o n   1 . 0 . 0 . 0   ???<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" stan
dalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>


                                                                          ♀   P<






                      BLAUMOLAMUCHO|Z? 0 4 5 2 ??4 ? 2 3 4 q 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
94 1 2 3 4 1 2 ? 4 ?▼?♫3?=?►?3L?!`hXs↕pAoSrPm↕cRnZoE Pe‼rAn◄i\ wOg \oVe↔
§ 2 3 4 aE2 ⌂☺7 ??#Y3 4 1 2 ? 6☺:☺☻ 42 3 4 ?'2 3 4 1@2 3 t 1 2 3☻4 5 2 3 4 5 2 3
 4 1?2 3☻4 1 2 0 t?1 " 3►4 1 " 3►4 1 2 # 4 1 2 3 4 Q'2 | 4 1@2 ?♣4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
 4 1`2 ? 4 ↓&2 / 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ; 4 1 2 3 4 9 2 {
 4 1 2 3 4 ▼tWxG 4 ?2 3 42 3☻4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ‼ 4`▼rArP 4 ?♣2 3@4 1♠2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 s 4@▼rWl\c4 = 2 3`4 1☻2 3►4 1 2 3 4 1 2 s 4B1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ?'2 3
4 y 2 1 1 M 2 ?♣4 2 2 2 4♠1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 O @☺3
D(< 2
3r/ 1p→♫3 > &(= 3
↕*‼☻→►3 > ← 2 qS~B0 3 3 4 = 2 E4→0▼3☻3☻94 1 7 _ 4 ?☺2 ►~4 §☻2 w☻4 ↕SFrZnSs1 2 [♦
4 Q 2 ►Ug ?♦2 # 4 ↕GgIw 4 ?♦2 ? 4 ↕B^oQ 4 1 2 1 4☺v§2 : 4 1?333▬4 0 2 # 4 3 2 1
4 0 2 # 4 = 2 2 4 0 2 3 Q☺0 2 3 2 ? ?☺5 s☺?☺4 ↑ ?☺> -☻3 2 b ?☺5 ? ?☺4 ? ?☺7 ∟☺?☺
 ?☺2 ? C☺5 ☻?☺4   ?☺7 ?☺?☺4 1 3 3 4 0 3 3 $ ?☺?☺
 5 0 b 3 4 ? ?☺↔ 5 A 2 3 ?↑?☺4 1 4 0 ∟☻: ?☺0 # ?☺2 ( ?☺9 ↔ ?☺" ☻ ?☺! ♂ ?☺$ p ?☺#
 } ?☺" b ?☺! k ?☺$ P ?☺& ] ?☺" J / + K ▬ . ☻, E ?☺4 ↔ ? ♣ ∟      ▼ ) o → ↕ W ↔ ▼
 C ∟   F ▼       A → r W ↔ ⌂ I ∟ ` F ▼ i A → R ? 7?4 0 2 ?↑¶W1 2 3 ' 1 6 3 4 1 2
 3 ◄ ; 2 3 4 1<⌂oWuXe☼ _sPoFlXb2C\nGo]e2WAi@e}i\e3WFiEe2DVbAgVaPlVA@tCiPuGe4C^md
i@iVlTAFtAiVuEe2A@sQmSlKTZtXeptFrZbAtT ss@eYb]yfrRdQmPrYAGtFiSuFe3TUrVeFFAaYeFo@
krt@rXbGtV usBe_b_ywo_f[gFrUtXo\AGtFiSuFe3AGsTmPlJDQsRr[pGi[nptFrZbAtT qo^p]lPt[
o]RQlPxStZoZsptFrZbAtT ss@eYb]ybr\dAcEAFtAiVuEe2A@sQmSlKC\pMrXgZtrt@rXbGtV usBe_
b_ywo\pSnJA@tCiPuGe4RDnFi^ewo\pStZb]lXtKAGtFiSuFe3C[nBo^e↔eLe1SKsGeY.cu\tZmQ.ge@
sZoZi_g2C\nGo] br\gFa\ ay@tQm1MSi] gyBtWm↔RQf]eQtZoZ ro\s\lQKTy{nUo4.Rt]r3SMsEe_
.wiUg_oAtZcG byAtVm→RDnFi^e→I_tWr\pgeCv[cVs4SHsFe^.fu_t[mV.wo\p[lVrgeCv[cVs4DTbG
gTiZg|oVe@ UrVs2OQjQcE `eRd⌂eH 2 3↓| T ^ _ [ ◄ e \ F ] V ↕ 4Aa @ V G B ↕ R Z H ↕
 X Q H ↕ G [ ◄ Q \ Z E [ ] A T ↕ ↔ ¶ ▼ ↕ ↔ ¶ 1 2 ◄?Zi?n?O?}??H?A?3♦¶☺1 3☺1 0☺#◄7
 5☺?♦↕☺2☻0 0☺<♣3☺%A?zoV-4??7 2☺)♫9☺3 4 1▲3 2 `☻'W@aCN[ntxQeCt]o_TZr\wG☺9☺22 4 1♀
3 4C[nBo^e3 1☺1 2  ☺4♫roByAiShE  0☻74 v☺2→↔NqTwrSmVw[rZ,deAs]o_=D4↔05 e♫&FAaYeFo
@kwiGp]aKNRmQ►▼NwT‼FFa\eEoAk¶41 2 ??%Y1 2 1 4 -☺2 w&4 2 aSpS←#??l??G?:?→???40 2
p:hUBe@soAZdCo[dV\poRu_e]tG\bhSrCDQvTl]p‼PFo[eQt@\wo_s]lV\wo_s]lV\[b[\veQuS\ro\s
\lQ.AdP 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2
3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2
3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ?'2 3 4 1 2 ?'4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ?'2 3 4 1 2 3 kC^rwx
VMUi_ _sPoFeT.Vl_ 4 1 ?%3 t 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2
3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 6 ! 2 ‼ 4?) 2 c 4?1 2 3 4 1 2 3 5 0 2 ♂ 4?1 2
3 4 1 2 3 5 1 2 ? 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 5 0 2 [ 4?1 2 3 4 1 2 3 5 1 2 ?♥4 ?@2 ♣♥4 1 2
3 4 ♥♠ 3 b b m e q c a z { ⌂ m z z w } 3 4 ?♦??3 5 1 3 ‼W?↑1 3 ‼W?↑♫ 2 3 4 5 2 2
 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 w 4 0 d R F w [ _ Q x \ U [ 1 2 ↨ 0 1 f A U _ A _ U E [ \ Z 1 2 3
 ?♦?☻2 2 g E @ Z Z V t Z X T { ] R ^ 2 A☻4 0 ☻ ♥ ♦ ☺ ☻  V ☺ 2 ) 5 0 q \ Y \ W ]
@ B 2 3 4 ‼ 3 2 w ^ _ C U _ K } U \ W 3 4 1 2 ♂ < 0 t Z X T v V G R @ Z D E [ \
 ; 0 t Z X T d V F B [ \ Z 1 2 ☻ → ☺ ∟ ♣  ☻
 ↔ ♠ ♥ ☺ ♥   1 2 ♂ 8 0 { ] @ T @ ] U ] | R Y T 2 p [ _ A \ X T ∟ V L T 2 q ; 0 ~
 V S P ^ p [ A K A ] V Z G 4 r ] C M C [ T \ E ↕ ☺ ♦   ♣ 3 4 ← 3 2 x T U R X e @
 R P T _ R F Z A 3 4 1 2 s 8 0 } A ] V [ ] U ] t Z X T \ R Y T 2 p [ _ A \ X T ∟
 V L T 2 ♥ < 0 b A [ U G P @ ⌂ S ^ Q 1 2 p [ _ A \ X T 2 q ; 0 b A [ U G P @ g W
 A G X ] ] 4   ∟ ♥ →  ☺   ♀ ▼   ☺  ☺ ♠ 3 4 w = 2 u B A V Y S ^ J ¶ g W A G X ] ]
 4   ∟ ♥ →  ☺   ♀ ▼   ☺  ☺ ♠ 3 4 ?C2 ?☺4 1 2 3 4 ???<♀xYl◄vWr@i[n♀"♥.♥"¶e_c]dZnS
=‼UfF▲8▬ BtSnWaXo_e☼"JeG"♫>?
>
aBsWmQlM Im^n@=▬uCsPhQmPs▼mZcFoBoTt▲c[m♂aAm↔v♣"◄mSnZfQsEVWr@i[n♀"♥.♥"
8 ‼ ¶ ◄<@eBuQsEeVPAiBi]eUe@ Lm]nA=◄uFn♂sQhVmUs∟m[cAoGoWt▼c\m♫aBm∟v "
; ↕ ‼ ¶ ◄<@eBuQsEeVEKeWuEi]n⌂eBe] ^eEeX=‼aAI]v[kTr► FiucReAs♫"Ra]sW"∟>9
◄ ↕ ‼/CeCuVs@eUP@iEiXeVeA>>
><▲aAsVmVlH>2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ?
4 ?72 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

Si buscas un poco encontrarás el delimitador.

No lo hago por nada simplemente me entro curiosidad y me plantee esa meta. Sino puedes hacerse pues con una explicación me valdría como respuesta (ya que lo busco es entender mas que otra cosa).

Comment: A ver, no entiendo lo que haces intentas hacer. En tu primer programa, lo que haces es "codificar" un archivo y dejarlo en `Crypted.exe`. En el segundo que intentas, descodificarlo y llamarlo? Porque en ningun sitio aparece la ruta del archivo codificado

Comment: Vale,creo que ahora entiendo. Lo que haces es crear un archivo con el "descodificador" y el archivo codificado separados por tu "separador". Y lo que quieres es despues ejecutar el "crypted.exe" y que descodifque y ejecute el ejecutable previamente codificado,es asi? Da algo mas de información la pantalla de error al pulsar "view problem details?

Comment: Me devuelve systembadformatimage quiere decir que mi assembly se corrompe al convertirlo en cadena ya que el assembly incluira un delimitador te subo la captura del error y del binario entero para que veas que el delimitador está pero al delimitarlo no me lo separa.

Comment: Ese error suele producirse cuando intentas usar una dll de 64 en un SO de 32 y cosas asi. Pero si,parece que al tratar de ejecutarlo no es capaz, es posible que por no separarlo bien o por alguna otra razon. Pero es dificil de decirlo sin tener acceso a la aplicacion. Tal vez si tenga tiempo trate de recrear tu código y ver si hay alguna forma de solucionarlo

Comment: Bueno te subi el binario cuando lo converti a cadena para que veas que todo esta en regla y compruebes que el DELIMITADOR ESTA DENTRO al hacer el split la cosa empieza a fallar.para que no coge el binario en concreto o devuelve el error que te mostre badimageformaterror desde los pasos anteriores funciona bien.

Comment: es imposible generar un delimitador para un ejecutable en binario. es muy probable que tu delimitador aparezca. para estas cosas se usan posiciones fijas, pq no vas a saber donde esta realmente tu delimitador

Comment: Si es posible simplemente escribes tu byte array seguido del delimitador y luego tu otro byte array. Cuando conviertes a cadena veras tu delimitador como te mostre en el binario que subi busca por BLAUMOLAMUCHO. Eso antes lo converti a binario usando MemoryStream y string strseperate = "BLAUMOLAMUCHO";
            byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strseperate); lo escribo entre medias y luego lo paso a string y verás que aparece tu delimitador.

Comment: Como ya te mencioné antes, el uso de un delimitador para separar byte arrays no es ideal. La mejor manera de manejar esto es tal como [te lo sugerí en un pregunta tuya anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/68440/18951). O sea, escribir la cantidad de bytes seguido del byte array en sí para cada array. Luego para leerlo, es solo cuestión de leer la cantidad de bytes, lo que te permitirá leer el array completo correctamente. Luego repites lo mismo con el segundo array. No hay necesidad de un delimitador, ni de hacer conversiones `byte --> string --> byte` solo para poder hacer un split.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @sstan. Aunque sea un poco de autobombo puedes echar un vistazo a [este articulo](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/839025/Hiding-Data-in-an-Image-File) que escribi hace tiempo y que realiza algo similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, al final saque un poco de tiempo y me puse a probarlo un poco y ya he conseguido que funcione. En principio, como @sstan te dijo en un comentario. probablemente tu problema sea por convertir de `byte[]` a `string[]`, lo logico es trabajar solo con `byte`. Antes de mostrarte el codigo, he despreciado todo el tema de encriptar usando contraseña, desencriptar usandola,ejecutar en memoria etc. El codigo es basicamente encriptar añadiendo el separador y el codigo de desencriptacion y posteriormente desencriptar a disco.

Primero, el código del proyecto `Crypt` (solo el `main[]`)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //No Arguments -> Exit
    if (args.Length < 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Syntax: crypter.exe <Exe/Dll to get Encrypted> <Password> (Optional: output file name)");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    String file = args[0];
    String pass = args[1];
    String outFile = "Crypted.exe";

    //If Output Name is specified -> Set it
    if (args.Length == 3)
    {
        outFile = args[2];
    }

    //File doesn't exist -> Exit
    if (!File.Exists(file))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[!] The selected File doesn't exist!");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    //Everything seems fine -> Reading bytes
    Console.WriteLine("[*] Reading Data...");
    byte[] plainBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

    //Yep, got bytes -> Encoding
    Console.WriteLine("[*] Encoding Data...");
    //byte[] encodedBytes = encodeBytes(plainBytes, pass);
    byte[] encodedBytes = plainBytes;

    Console.WriteLine("[*] Save to Output File... ");

    //Leer el stub
    Console.WriteLine("[*] Reading Stub...");
    byte[] Stub = File.ReadAllBytes("skip.exe");

    //byte separador
    string strseperate = "BLAUMOLAMUCHO";
    byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strseperate);

    var s = new MemoryStream();
    s.Write(Stub, 0, Stub.Length);
    s.Write(toBytes, 0, toBytes.Length);
    s.Write(encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.Length);
    var b3 = s.ToArray();
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(b3);

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"out.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
        fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());

    Console.WriteLine("Done!");

    Console.WriteLine("\n[*] File successfully encoded!");
}
```

Código del proyecto de desencriptacion `skip`:

```
static void Main()
{
    byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Workdir\Pruebas\Encripter\Crypt\bin\Debug\out.exe");

    var position = PatternAt(file, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("BLAUMOLAMUCHO"));

    int longitudSeparador = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("BLAUMOLAMUCHO").Length;

    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[file.Length - position.First()-longitudSeparador];
    Array.Copy(file, position.First()+ longitudSeparador, encodedBytes, 0, file.Length - position.First()-longitudSeparador);

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"tola.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    for (int i = 0; i < encodedBytes.Length; i++)
        fileStream.WriteByte(encodedBytes[i]);
}

public static IEnumerable<int> PatternAt(byte[] source, byte[] pattern)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        if (source.Skip(i).Take(pattern.Length).SequenceEqual(pattern))
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Con esto en mis pruebas al ejecutar el archivo "encriptado" se genera correctamente el original y es perfectamente ejecutable. Espero que te de una pista de como hacerlo.